# Passing a parameter without invoking Hibernate (GORM) while passing data from view to controller in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, model-view-controller, grails-orm

When generated automatically, the views generally have code like this:

```
<td><g:link action="show" id="${xyzInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: xyzInstance, field: "name")}</g:link></td>
```

And when we click the URL, it redirects it to the `show` method in the controller. I have a set of records which I am displaying in the `index` without querying from the default database. I am getting them from an XML. and I would like to send one of the values (which is clicked) to the Controller. They don't have an ID field. so when I change `${xyzInstance.id}` to `${xyzInstance.name}` it throws an `org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException`. How do I pass the name from view to controller bypassing the Hibernate layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can't pass `xyzInstance.name` to id because `id` is mapped to hibernate. So there's type mismatch because `name` is a string and `id` is an integer type.

You should pass `name` as param and retrieve it in your controller instead.
So instead of doing this

```
<g:link action="show" id="${xyzInstance.name}">${fieldValue(bean: xyzInstance, field: "name")}</g:link>
```

You would do this:

```
<g:link action="show" params="[name:${xyzInstance.name}]">${fieldValue(bean: xyzInstance, field: "name")}</g:link>
```

And then in your controller, check if name is not null and use it instead e.g

```
def show(){
    if(params.name){
        //do some thing with name here 
    }

}
```

Hope this helps